# Regarding page title & meta tag generation from server end and render in page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I searching for a tips to generate page title & meta tag from server end and render in page.
I got this trick.

First approach would be to Make a parent interface for all your model objects. and you could have:

```
public interface IBaseMasterViewDto
{
    int PageId { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
    string MetaDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Thus in your master view you could use

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<IBaseMasterViewDto>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">

  <head>
    <title><%: Model.Title %></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<%: Model.MetaKeywords %>" />
    <meta name="description" content="<%: Model.MetaDescription %>" />
```

If there is no concept like master page in MVC3 so guide me how can i implement the above code for layout page or make the above code compatible for mvc3 layout page. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there is no concept like master page in MVC3 so guide me how can i implement the above code for layout page or make the above code compatible for mvc3 layout page.

Let's first try to clear the notions here. ASP.NET MVC 3 is a server side framework allowing to develop web applications on the top of ASP.NET implementing the MVC pattern.

It supports different views for rendering the markup:

- ASP.NET WebForms
- Razor
- ...

The ASP.NET WebForms view has notion of MasterPage files (`.master`). The Razor view has the same equivalent called Layouts (`.cshtml`).

So you could apply exactly the same notion in a Razor Layout file:

```
@model IBaseMasterViewDto

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">
<head>
    <title>@Model.Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="@Model.MetaKeywords" />
    <meta name="description" content="@Model.MetaDescription" />
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but how to populate meta tags & page title from action method. do i need to my model extend the interface called IBaseMasterViewDto ? please guide me how to implement it. also tell me would it be best approach if not then guide me with best approach. thanks